# Non-dialog sub menus?

Tags: android, menu, submenu, slidingdrawer

I've seen several instances of a menu with a "More ..." button that appears to open something like a list on a sliding drawer instead of the standard submenu popup dialog.  Is this actually being done with a sliding drawer, or is there some menu setting I'm missing?

I forgot to mention, this is for android apps.

Thanks.

Comment: That would be helpful, wouldn't it? 0.o  I meant for android.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to screenshot of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Creating Submenus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) on http://developer.android.com

Comment: lol, I'm so f'n stupid... I read that, but had it in my head that you had to create your own "More" section.  ...just have more than 6 and it's automatic.  Thanks for forcing me to open my eyes.